# Joomla2.5 bottom menu issue

Tags: css, joomla2.5

I am working on a joomla 2.5 site and  am required to insert a menu module at the the bottom i.e the footer of the template.I have three items in the middle div ( module ).All i want is that there is some spacing between the three items and also that the menu are displayed inline.so i did add a custom class suffix to the module and am using it in the CSS to exactly match the one i truly require but all i get is somehow my padding set to 0 and the padding-left that i specify in my custom CSS isnt applied.

Please help me with its

1. Display:inline
2. spacing between the items.

Please note that this custom CSS should be applied to ONLY AND ONLY this module.because otherwise the whole look of the lists and unordered lists of the site changes.

i am new to it so i am able to exactly figure why it doesnt work

[image: This is the firebug screenshot of the HTML code][image: As you can see there is a gap between the border at the top of it and the menu downwards]

Comment: Are you able to provide a link? That would make it easy. The image you posted doesn't help.

Comment: I am actually editing it on my localhost ( XAMPP ) havent yet hosted it.Meanwhile here are the links of the pictures above.You can see the image much clear than here.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8y30s8qkgnel4zy/issue.jpg

https://www.dropbox.com/s/156ogic8hb98br3/issue1.jpg

As you can see from the images.
if somehow i am able to change the CSS.The white border is supposed to be just above the " all rights reserved" part because of the paddind specified somehow affects the height and that's what i dont.

Comment: Try making up a small demo that illustrates the issue, which you can post here or on a site like jsFiddle.

Comment: try overriding css using !important.ex: padding-left:10px !important;

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to affect only the module with the menu you will want to add a module class suffix in the module parameters in the advance module options (it looks like you did that with bottom_footer_menu).

Next, margins don't work on inline elements. You will need to either float the LIs or set them to display as inline-block.